# Override onPostExecute() in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I can't seem to figure this out. As far as I know, I have followed the guidelines for extending the AsyncTask class, and all other related questions on SO are not helpful in my case.

here is my class that extends AsyncTask:

```
package com.ck.nisttime;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Created by ck on 12/15/15.
 */
public class FetchTime extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    private int port=13;
    private String host="time-b.nist.gov";
    private MainActivity mainAct;

    public FetchTime(Context context){
        this.mainAct=(MainActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String time="";
        try {
            Socket socket=new Socket(host,port);
            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            in.readLine();
            time=in.readLine();
            socket.close();
        } catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
            Log.e("ck", uhe.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecuted(String time){
        mainAct.showTime(time);
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I attempt to override onPostExecute, stating 'Method does not override method from its superclass'. I think I could just make a class variable to store the string and just change it to `...extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>...` but thats not how it should be done.

Comment: Sorry for wasting time and space guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistyped the name of it, you have:

```
onPostExecuted
```

but it should be:

```
onPostExecute
```

(no extra 'd' at the end).